# FileVersionInfo doesn't match Details tab in Explorer

Tags: c#, fileversioninfo

I'm attempting to use `C#` and [`System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo`](http://System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo) to extract the version information from a list of files. My purpose for doing this is to keep track of unique filepath and version combinations. When the files change I'd like various things to happen depending on what exactly changed.

I've used both the [`FileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion.aspx) and [`ProductVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productversion.aspx) properties of [`FileVersionInfo`](http://System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo) to no avail. Both report a different version number than what is reported in explorer.

An example using explorer.exe

```
Explorer Details tab reports: "6.1.7601.17567" (for both File and Product)
FVI.ProductVersion reports: "6.1.7600.16385"
FVI.FileVersion reports: "6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the `ProductVersion` property doesn't match the ProductMajorPart/MinorPart/BuildPart/PrivatePart... To get the actual version you can do this:

```
var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);
var productVersion = new Version(
                           fvi.ProductMajorPart,
                           fvi.ProductMinorPart,
                           fvi.ProductBuildPart,
                           fvi.ProductPrivatePart);
var fileVersion = new Version(
                           fvi.FileMajorPart,
                           fvi.FileMinorPart,
                           fvi.FileBuildPart,
                           fvi.FilePrivatePart);
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks. The infinite wisdom of Microsoft.

Comment: The "some reason" is that there are separate string and binary forms of the property in the resource compiled into the executable, and there's no requirement that the string form match the binary form.  Which it doesn't in the question.  The string form has all of that `(win7_rtm.090713-1255)` on the end, notice, and clearly a different third and fourth numeric part.